# Empty json using Spray without quotation marks?

Tags: json, scala, spray

How do you return empty json using Spray without quotation marks ?

I have following routing

```
path("empty") {
  post {
    entity(as[EmptyJson]) { empty=>
       complete("""{}""")
       }    
    }
}
```

and

```
POST http://localhost:8181/empty
Content-Type: application/json
{ }
```

yields

```
"{}"
// POST http://localhost:8181/empty
// HTTP/1.1 200 OK
// Server: spray-can/1.3.4
```

Is there a way to complete routing with empty valid JSON  using Spray ?

Answer (score 4):

If you have configured marshallers, then it should be enough to use an empty object as the response?

```
complete(JsObject.empty)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have json4s native in use for serialization.  JsObject is from spray-json right. It returns    {
  "fields": null
}.  I need just  {}

Comment: Have you tried `JObject()` instead of spray's JsObject? Looks like an equivalent https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/0b28498f065ed8365e4e336a5fec1ec5d4e15649/ast/src/main/scala/org/json4s/JsonAST.scala#L158

Comment: I did, and it returns null.

Comment: JObject(List()) also returns null.

Comment: How do you turn json into string for response? Is it something provided by json4s, or you wrote own marshaller?

Comment: Tried pretty much everything, but here's one I tried.   class EmptySerializer extends CustomSerializer[EmptyJson](format => (
         {
           case JObject(List()) =>
             new EmptyJson()
         },
         {
           case x: EmptyJson =>
             JObject(List())
         }
       ))   It turns {} into EmptyJson case class alright.

Comment: Except for quotation following works    path("empty") {
    post {
      entity(as[EmptyJson]) { empty=>
        println(empty)
        complete(write(EmptyJson()))
      }
    }    i.e. I get response   "{}"
// POST http://localhost:8181/empty
// HTTP/1.1 200 OK
// Server: spray-can/1.3.4